# Python replace part of long url

Tags: python, regex

I have a long url like

```
https://yyyyyy.com/yyyyy/xxxxx/yyyyy/yyyyyy/yyyyy/pppp/kkkk
```

And I want to replace the xxxx part to zzzz

I tried with the re.sub

```
b = url.split('/')[-6] #which gives me the right part of the url to change
newurl = re.sub(b, 'zzzz',  url)
```

But when i print it i still get the old url.. Any idea?

Comment: [Works on my machine](https://www.ideone.com/tXwghX). Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with replace.

```
url = 'https://yyyyyy.com/yyyyy/xxxxx/yyyyy/yyyyyy/yyyyy/pppp/kkkk'
sp = url.split('/')[-6]
new_url = url.replace(sp, 'zzzz')

print(new_url)
```

**Output**

```
https://yyyyyy.com/yyyyy/zzzz/yyyyy/yyyyyy/yyyyy/pppp/kkkk
```

Be careful, because this will replace all the `'xxxx'` in your `url`. For example if you have.

```
url = 'https://yyyyyy.com/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/yyyyyy/xxxxx/pppp/kkkk'
sp = url.split('/')[-6]
new_url = url.replace(sp, 'zzzz')

print(new_url)
```

**Output**

```
https://yyyyyy.com/zzzzz/zzzz/zzzzz/yyyyyy/zzzzz/pppp/kkkk
```

Comment: Thanks worked... Didnt think it was just this easy..

Comment: This would replace all occurrences of `xxxxxx` in `url`, not just the one at index `-6`.

Answer (score 1):

You can slice and join the list you split from `url` instead:

```
url = 'https://yyyyyy.com/yyyyy/xxxxx/yyyyy/yyyyyy/yyyyy/pppp/kkkk'
b = url.split('/')
newurl = '/'.join(b[:-6] + ['zzzz'] + b[-5:])
```

`newurl` would become:

```
https://yyyyyy.com/yyyyy/zzzz/yyyyy/yyyyyy/yyyyy/pppp/kkkk
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this,

```
import re
s = "https://yyyyyy.com/yyyyy/xxxxx/yyyyy/yyyyyy/yyyyy/pppp/kkkk"
new_url = re.sub('[xxxxx]', 'z', s)
print(new_url)
```